# Can Active Directory Authenticate a User Using an MD5 Hashed Password

Tags: authentication, active-directory

Under normal circumstances to authenticate a user in AD, one sends AD the user's clear text password (using SSL, hopefully).  For reasons that are out of my control, I only have an MD5 hash of the user's password.  Is it possible to configure AD to authenticate users using this hash instead of the original password?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation it is now apparent that AD will not support the scenario.  AD does not expose its internal hash externally, and besides, it doesn't use MD5 to hash passwords.  It uses something stronger.